# Making a content "feed" with mysql database and php, is this a safe way?

Tags: php, mysql, database, feed

I'm making a a side bar feed that will display the 10 most current things submitted into my database. I'm very new to all of this, so I am wondering.. is this an ok way of going about doing it? it works.. not automatically but when i submit something into my database, it goes there.. i submit something else and then the top goes to to the second..! i just cant shake the feeling that maybe this isnt a good way to do it.

the top 3 sections

```
<div class="span3 offset3">

<?php include 'feed/one.php'; ?>

    <ul class="nav nav-list well">


        <li class="nav-header"></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HIT INFO</a></li>
        <?php while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

        <li><a href="<?php print $row['link']?>"><?php 
             Print "<tr>"; 
             Print "<th>Hit:</th> <td>".$row['hit'] . "</td> "; 
             Print "<th>Amount:</th> <td>".$row['amount'] . " </td>"; 
             Print "<th>Category:</th> <td>".$row['category'] . "</td></tr> ";
             Print "<br><br/>"; 
             Print "</table>";?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>

        <li class="divider"></li>
        <?php $data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM hit ORDER BY hit_id DESC LIMIT 1, 1"); ?>
        <?php while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

        <li><a href="<?php print $row['link']?>"><?php 
             Print "<tr>"; 
             Print "<th>Hit:</th> <td>".$row['hit'] . "</td> "; 
             Print "<th>Amount:</th> <td>".$row['amount'] . " </td>"; 
             Print "<th>Category:</th> <td>".$row['category'] . "</td></tr> ";
             Print "<br><br/>"; 
             Print "</table>";?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <?php $data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM hit ORDER BY hit_id DESC LIMIT 2, 1"); ?>
        <?php while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

        <li><a href="<?php print $row['link']?>"><?php 
             Print "<tr>"; 
             Print "<th>Hit:</th> <td>".$row['hit'] . "</td> "; 
             Print "<th>Amount:</th> <td>".$row['amount'] . " </td>"; 
             Print "<th>Category:</th> <td>".$row['category'] . "</td></tr> ";
             Print "<br><br/>"; 
             Print "</table>";?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <?php $data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM hit ORDER BY hit_id DESC LIMIT 3, 1"); ?>
        <?php while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

        <li><a href="<?php print $row['link']?>"><?php 
             Print "<tr>"; 
             Print "<th>Hit:</th> <td>".$row['hit'] . "</td> "; 
             Print "<th>Amount:</th> <td>".$row['amount'] . " </td>"; 
             Print "<th>Category:</th> <td>".$row['category'] . "</td></tr> ";
             Print "<br><br/>"; 
             Print "</table>"; ?></a></li>
             <?php } ?>
```

the data that gets submitted gets displayed on my main page until something else gets submitted, goes to the "feed", and also goes to another page that shows the past data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have anything the user can intercept, so "safe" is a non issue.

You are querying illogically though. There's no reason to repeat the same query with multiple offsets all over the page when you can just fetch the data initially and use that object to relay the content where needed. Run a query like this at the beginning of the file, or ideally before any output is rendered.

```
"SELECT * FROM hit ORDER BY hit_id DESC LIMIT 4"
```

Now you have 4 items, so accessing those throughout the page could be something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list well">
    <li class="nav-header"></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">HIT INFO</a></li>
        <?php while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()): ?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?php print $row['link']?>">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Hit:</th> <td><?php echo $row['hit']; ?></td>
                        <th>Amount:</th> <td><?php echo $row['amount']; ?></td>
                        <th>Category:</th> <td><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <br><br/> 
                </table>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
 </ul>
```

Now, you have a few markup errors there. You close a table you never open. This can only in a small way be considered tabular data, so tables are probably not the best way to do this anyhow. I myself don't understand your use of th and td in this way, but if it works for you then good.

You should break out of php to display html. echoing something like `"<th>"` is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of each time querying the database and getting a record to show it, you should do it in a single query which fetches the number of rows you need:

```
<?php $data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM hit ORDER BY hit_id DESC LIMIT 1, N"); ?>
```

This fetches the first N rows, where N has to be numeric of course. Then you should loop throw the rows and print it just the way you are doing now. The only difference is that it might take you a while to get the nuances of opening/looping/closing tables correctly, but it is a really good investment of your time to wrap your head around it!

Answer (score 0):

You're actually using the `hit_id` field to  order the data you get from the database.

If you want actually to retrieve the "10 most current things submitted into my database", you'll need something else than an auto-incremented ID. (Something like a `COUNT` on the `amount` row). It will depends on the actual value / way to fill this field but it might look like this instead :

```
SELECT * FROM hit GROUP BY Category ORDER BY amount DESC;
```

Concerning this part :

> but when i submit something into my database, it goes there.. i
>   submit something else and then the top goes to to the second

The reason is quite simple, you're using `ORDER BY hit_id DESC`, that's why the last inserted ID is coming first.